# Shell script to connect via ssh with retry

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, expect

I am looking a way to create a shell script for connect to a remote machinne using a ssh protocol, user, password and port. The final script must retry connect at least three times on time out.

I have found a lot of samples on how to get a connection or test a connection using expect script or shell script running expect, but none doing retry connection on timeout.

I am pasteing some of the samples that I have used for get a ssh conection like the script that I am using. My question will be how to get retry on timeout?

Thanks a lot

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh aspen
expect "password: "
send "PASSWORD\r"
expect "$ "
send "ps -ef |grep apache\r"
expect "$ "
send "exit\r"
```

Comment: Have you tried writing a `for` or `while` loop?

Answer (score 0):

I think the key is to expect the timeout event. Code would be some like this

```
expect {
    timeout {
        send_user "retry"
        spawn ssh apen
        exp_continue
    }
    "continue connecting (yes/no)?" {
        send "yes\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    -re "\[Pp]assword:" {
        send -- "$password\r"
    }
    "Host key verification failed." {
        expect_after;       # do not exit on eof
        if {[regexp -line "^Offending key in.*\.ssh/known_hosts:(\[0-9]*)" \
                 $expect_out(buffer) dummy lineNum] ==1} {
            send_user "Delete stored finger print? (n/y) ";
            expect_user {
                -re "\[yY]" {exec sed -i "${lineNum}d" [glob "~/.ssh/known_hosts"]}
                -re "\[^Yy]" {}
            }
            exit 0
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that the "timeout" line is NOT tested. I copied this snippet from my code, where the timeout line is "timeout {exit}".

I am not very sure if spawning a new ssh in the expect clause will work. But, at least you can catch the timeout event and put it in a loop